# android aar file embedding other arr files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

Is it possible to create an android aar file that will embed other aar dependencies ?
I want an aar file that resembles an uber jar.

I am using gradle to build my aars.

Comment: I am not aware that this is possible. And since the "uber jar" approach is considered by many to be a bad idea, you may wish to consider other options (e.g., artifacts in repositories using transitive dependencies to express their inter-relationships).

Comment: Yes it's possible to create AAR file that embed other aar dependencies.create AAR file using android studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare the "uber jar" approach has the advantage that the code can be better obfuscated.